# Sending one request continuously after 5 sec

Tags: jmeter, ruby-jmeter

My thread group is having 5 http samples requests which are running single times each. 
After that I want to send a single http sample request after every 5 seconds which is running after the above 4 samples.

Please suggest

Comment: Can clarify your question..

Answer (score 1):

After your first 4 samples, add a `Loop Controller` and set it its loop count to `Forever` (or however many you need). Add your 5th Sample to this `Loop Controller`. Then add a `Constant Timer` to that Sample with a `Thread Delay` of 5000 (it's measured in milliseconds).

If you checked `Forever` above, under your `Thread Group` you'll want to check the `Scheduler` and add a `duration` otherwise it will run, well, forever.

Answer (score 1):

Place 5th http sample request inside loop controller with `forever`checkbox enabled so that it would be endless running till the time execution completes. Also place one constant timer as a child of 5th request with 5 secs delay

Structure would be like this

[image]